# message mediation data type error in wso2am

Tags: wso2-api-manager

i am trying to get system time with the following sequence (actually it is part of a sequence)

```
            <property name="gov:/oauth_endpoint/generated_time" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="registry" type="LONG" />
```

but it give's me the following error
"Unknown type : LONG for the property mediator or the property value cannot be converted into the specified type."

Comment: Can you try by removing `scope="registry"`? [`SYSTEM_TIME`](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/property-reference/message-context-properties/#system_time) is a synapse message context property and if a property has no defined scope, it [defaults to the Synapse message context scope](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/property-mediator/#property-mediator)